# Get-AdUser | Out-GridView too slow

Tags: powershell, gridview

I want to select users from Active Directory with Grid-View in a large Active Directory...

First of all, source code:

```
$Func_DeployVM_SelectedUser = $null
$Func_DeployVM_SelectedUser = get-aduser -filter {enabled -eq $true} |
  Select Name, UserPrincipalName, sAMAccountName, DistinguishedName |
    Out-GridView -Title "Select User Name to add" -OutputMode Single -OutVariable UserChoice
```

Now I get the selected value with this code:

```
$Func_DeployVM_SelectedUser.Name
```

But this works only when I wait 5-10 sec. before I click one User Account. If I click too fast, the variable is empty.

My guess is that the Active Directory is too large.

Anyone knows a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Which version of powershell are you using and how many users are you pulling this information for? If you are using an earlier version of powershell it is still loading every single property and passing it to out-grid its just only displaying the columns you selected. You may have to create a loop to a seperate psObject and then outgrid that object to get around this. On the otherhand if you are doing this for 5k plus users, you may just be SOL.

Comment: You may speed up your query a little bit more when you limit it with a `-SearchBase`

Comment: I use PowerShell 5.1... I count right now all User Objects = 12.168 Users.

Comment: Enclose the `Get-ADUser .. |Select ...` statements in `()`, this way you know the query is done executing before you pipe the results to `Out-GridView`

Comment: haha, so easy... I don't know right now when you use () around your command it's excecuting before it's shown. Many thx dude!

Comment: In addition to Mathias' comment, I would try an [`-LDAPFilter`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527(v=ws.10).aspx) `"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"` rather than a local `-Filter`, this way you will only pull the enabled users to local and not all 12.168...

Comment: @iRon : I have stop the time `measure-command` . with `(get-aduser -ldapfilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))")` I need 9.9 Sec. and for `(get-aduser -filter {enabled -eq $true})` I nedd 7.8 Sec. It would be great to speed up a bit :)